# How can I display my buttons on their own line within a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to display the `<h1>` on it's own line as well as the `<h3>` and all the buttons on 1 line together. I am using flex and I know how to do this normally, what I tried to do was `display: block;` on the buttons and h3 to have them on their own lines, this didn't work and I tried googling my way and finding some kind of flexbox guide to figure it out myself.

```css
body {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: #6987D5;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container h1 {}

.container button {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #315dcc;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
  <h3>00:00</h3>
  <button type="button">Start</button>
  <button type="button">Stop</button>
  <button type="button">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for `flex-direction: column;`?

Comment: Check out my answer, maybe it will help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `<div>` around the buttons to combine them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: #6987D5;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container h1 {}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.container button {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #315dcc;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
  <h3>00:00</h3>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button">Start</button>
    <button type="button">Stop</button>
    <button type="button">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tree buttons in a row, they need their own flex container. To display items in a column, you don't need flex since that is the default behaviour.

HTML

```css
.container {
   display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
      <h3>00:00</h3>
      <div class="container">
         <button id="start">Start</button>
         <button id="stop">Stop</button>
         <button id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap buttons and text within separate container divs like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
    <h3>00:00</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button type="button">Start</button>
    <button type="button">Stop</button>
    <button type="button">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .container is flexed which is why you have everything flowing from left to right. You can set `flex-direction: column;` but that will just be complicating what is there by default.

All `h` element is blocked element which means they will fill up any available space. So remove `display: flex;` from the `.container` class selector and wrap your buttons in grid or flex container.

```
.button-group {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-colums: repeat(3, 1frm);
  gap:1rem;
 }
```

or

```
.button-group button{
  gap: 1rem; //May not work on all browsers
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

and

```
<div class='button-group'>
  <button>Start</button>
  <button>Stop</button>
  <button>End</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In theory you can just add:

```
flex-direction: column;
```

to the `.container` css
but it will make also start and stop buttons in column, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Tried already, I want the buttons to be inline which they aren't even after I do display inline and display inline-flex.